# Add and assign to a signal in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am developing a 10 point moving average filter for an assignment. I am taking small steps so that I can be sure each stage of my code is working. My first step is to take an input which is a standard logic vector (5 bits) and convert it to a signal of type integer for processing before converting back to a standard logic vector for output. My first block of code is:

```
library IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity AveFilter is
    port(   CLK     : in STD_LOGIC;
        RST     : in STD_LOGIC;
        ADC_In  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 4 downto 0);
        AveOut  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 4 downto 0)
        );
end AveFilter;


architecture Behavioral of AveFilter is
        signal adc_sum : integer := 0;
        type Circ_Buf is array (0 to 9) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);       
        signal ave_buf : Circ_Buf;

begin
    process (CLK, RST, ADC_In)

        variable idx : integer := 5;

    begin       

         ave_buf(0) <= ADC_In; 

         adc_sum <= to_integer(unsigned(ave_buf(0)));

         AveOut <= std_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(adc_sum, AveOut'length)); 

    end process;        
end architecture;
```

The above code simply takes the input value and assigns to the output; I have tested this with modelsim and it works as expected. I can also assign various hard coded values to `adc_sum` and they also apear on the out put as expected.

The problem I have is when I modify the code so that the current adc input is added to the previous value of `adc_sum` and then stored in `adc_sum` ie by doing this:

```
adc_sum <= adc_sum + to_integer(unsigned(ave_buf(0)));
```

When I view `AveOut` in model sim the values are always XXXX. I have looked at some VHDL examples and it looks like and I beleive that I should be able to perorm the above operation. Could someone please give me a clue as to what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: You are describing a clocked process without proper syntax. Google on VHDL clocked processes. And preferably synchronous reset. Then: `signal ave_buf : Circ_Buf := (others => (others => '0'));` to initialize. And why not make `ave_buf` an array of `unsigned`?

Comment: Hi JHBonarius Thank you for your suggestions too, they have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ave_buf` is probably undefined at the beginning. Try initializing it. If this works, you should also implement reset on it. Also, you should take action on rising edge of the clock. And `ADC_In` is unnecessary in the sensitivity list.

Comment: Hi Staszek
Thank you very much for your answer. I have added a check for a rising edge in my process so, and I now get the results I was expecting.